# Regex to scan integer and string from string in C

Tags: c, regex, string, scanf

I have a string that looks like this: `{opt,2}{home,4}...` I have to scan opt and 2 into a string and integer. I am doing this:

```
char str[40] = "{opt,2}{home,4}";
char s[20];
int *x;
sscanf(str, "{%[^,],%[0-9]}", s,&x);
```

This segfaults. What is the right way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To scan text like that, you don't need regex, you could just use simple `scanf` specifiers.

```
char s[16];   /* The string in the pair */
int n;        /* The integer in the pair */
int len;      /* The length of the pair */

for (; sscanf(buf, "{%[^,],%d}%n", s, &n, &len) == 2; buf += len) {
    /* use str and n */
}
```

The `%n` specifier simply receives the number of characters read in the `sscanf` call, and stores it in the matching argument (in this case, `len`). We use this value so that we can increment the `buf` that is being read from, so that the next string-int pair may be read.

Comment: Woops! You're right. I used len from here but actual scanf from your comment.